# Custom gnome sessions .desktop Vs .xsession

Tags: gnome, customization, gtk3, i3-wm

I've patched together a primitive understanding of gnome custom sessions from

- https://zork.net/~st/jottings/gnome-i3.html
- https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/session-custom.html.en
- https://www.maketecheasier.com/customize-the-gdm-sessions-list

My goal is to run **i3** with **gnome-flashback** on **Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS**. But these resources seem to offer conflicting instructions.

I created `/usr/share/xsessions/gnome-plus-i3.desktop` containing basic information on what is launched when my custom session, *GNOME Flashback (i3)*, is selected in the display manager.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=GNOME Flashback (i3)
Comment=This session logs you into GNOME Flashback with i3

# Don't continue if i3 doesn't exist.
TryExec=i3

# TODO: How can I define my own .target file here?
Exec=/usr/lib/gnome-session/run-systemd-session gnome-session-flashback.target

Type=Application
DesktopNames=GNOME-Flashback;GNOME;
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-flashback
```

**Question #1:** Should I define my own `.target` file on this line

```
Exec=/usr/lib/gnome-session/run-systemd-session gnome-session-flashback.target
```

I *assume* since I'm creating my own session that I want my own `.target` file. However, this doesn't seem to contain anything specific to a window manager:

```
[Unit]
Description=User systemd services for the GNOME Flashback sessions
Requires=graphical-session-pre.target
Requires=indicators-pre.target
# start/tear down graphical-session.target along with the ubuntu session
BindsTo=graphical-session.target
# session leader -- if this dies, die along with it
BindsTo=gnome-session.service
# here we list the indicators that we want to load
Wants=indicator-application.service
Wants=indicator-bluetooth.service
Wants=indicator-datetime.service
Wants=indicator-keyboard.service
Wants=indicator-messages.service
Wants=indicator-power.service
Wants=indicator-session.service
Wants=indicator-sound.service
Wants=indicator-printers.service
```

**Question 2:** If I define my own `.target` file, do I need to add it to `/usr/lib/systemd/user/` or can I provide a full-path and put it somewhere in my home dir?

**Question 2.5:** How does `/usr/lib/gnome-session/run-systemd-session` know where to find the `.target` file?

**Question 3:** Assuming I get this far, why do I need to use `.xsession`? It seems to do almost exactly the same as the `.desktop` file (runs a named gnome-session).

```bsh
# Menu tools use this value to decide which applications
# are approriate for the current session.
if [ -z $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP ]; then
    export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP="GNOME-Flashback:GNOME"
fi

# Run gnome-session and tell it to use our i3 session.
exec gnome-session --session=gnome-plus-i3 --disable-acceleration-check
```

**Question #4:** Is it necessary to start the various DBus services from the i3 configuration file (`~/.config/i3/config`) if they're all listed as `RequiredComponents` in `/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/gnome-plus-i3.session`?

```
# i3 config file (v4)
#
# Please see https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html for a complete reference!

set $mod Mod4

# ...omitted for brevity

# Start the various DBus services.
exec --no-startup-id /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-xsettings
exec --no-startup-id /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-keyboard
exec --no-startup-id /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-mouse
exec --no-startup-id /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-media-keys
exec --no-startup-id /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-sound
```

My `/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/gnome-plus-i3.session` file is

```
[GNOME Session]
# To create a session with all the required GNOME background services, the easiest thing is to use gnome-session.
# We’ll create a session that includes i3 and the GNOME Flashback goodies.

# Name of the session. This can be localized.
Name=GNOME Flashback (i3)

# List of component identifiers (desktop files) that are required by the session.
# The required components will always run in the session.
# Note that RequiredComponents aren’t executables, they’re the names of .desktop files.

RequiredComponents=gnome-flashback-init;gnome-flashback;i3;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sound;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Mouse;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings;org.gnome.Shell.Extensions;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.PrintNotifications;
```

**UPDATE**

**Answer #2:** [Desktop Entry Specification](https://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/) provides detailed information on [The Exec key](https://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/#exec-variables) https://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/#exec-variables

> The executable program can either be specified with its full path or
>   with the name of the executable only. If no full path is provided the
>   executable is looked up in the $PATH environment variable used by the
>   desktop environment.